# How to receive a transferred file on skype on Windows XP system using keyboard?

Tags: skype

I generally hate to use a mouse,it interrupts my working flow really, somehow couldn't download a transferred file sent by other people, anyone knows how to?

Answer (score 0):

[Keyboard navigation](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA3381/How-do-I-turn-on-keyboard-navigation-or-screen-reader-mode) lets you use your keyboard, rather than your mouse, to navigate menus in a software program or on the web. To enable extended keyboard navigation in Skype:

- Sign in to Skype.
- Click Tools > Accessibility.
- Select Extended Keyboard Navigation.

When the option is enabled, press Alt on your keyboard. The Skype menu names in the top tool bar are underlined.

[image]

To open a menu, press and hold Alt and the underlined letter of the menu name you’d like to navigate to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi，ahmed, i am aware of this availability of keyboard surfing skype, however, if someone sends me a file over skype dialogue box, there is no keyboard enabled to receive that, could you help on that one?